# Delphi XE6 MessageDlg window behind form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

In my app I call the MessageDlg function. The Dialog pops up behind the Form and locks the program as a result. How do I get the Dialog Window to appear on top of the form?

My code is:

```
MessageDlg('Printing Complete', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

Comment: Do you have any code that reproduces the fault? Because it works fine here. In other words, there's no question here until we have an MCVE.

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX?

Comment: I am using VCL. It all works fine here but not at the clients. Running Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: I have seen that issue on older Delphi versions (VCL) - happened even on Delphi 7. I don't think we ever found a good solution for it, only nasty work-arounds. Also, are you using VCL styles? THe problem persisted more when we had styles enabled.

Comment: @Jerry Delphi 7 didn't always handle ownership correctly. Long since fixed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Also seen in D2010 and DXE2, waiting to see it happen in XE7 now.

Comment: @Jerry only if you mess up the window owner

Comment: Also had it happen on random occasions in XE5. Looks like either a lot of people are seeing things or it never got fixed entirely. I swear I never fumbled around with a Window owner.

Comment: The code I am using is

Comment: What is unusual is that it seems to be random by machine. Two workstations running the same operating system will either experience it or not.

Comment: Is the form that remains in front of the MessageDlg set to have form style fsStayOnTop? If so, a call NormalizeTopMosts before and a call to RestoreTopMosts after the MessageDlg is called might help.

Comment: The form style is fsNormal. I tried both Application.NormalizeTopMosts and Application.NormalizeAllTopMosts to no avail.

Comment: @farley You need to isolate the problem. The code in the question works correctly. Try to make an MCVE.

Comment: @Tom An owned window is always on top of its owner. It is amazing how badly understood window ownership is in the Delphi world.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The problem is that if I create a new VCL app with a single form with a single button. The button only calls ' MessageDlg('Printing Complete', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0); ' It works on my computer but not on some of the clients.

Comment: Please re-read my most recent comment.

Comment: @David But how does one control the ownership of the MessageDlg?

Comment: The framework does it. You can find out by reading the source code if you wish. You need to isolate the problem. Clearly the owner is not set correctly, but in normal scenarios like your code in the Q, it is set correctly. So, until you can produce an MCVE there's nothing for us to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks. I know. I was just hoping someone had seen this as I cannot reproduce it on my system. I think while I search for this obscurity it might be faster to replace MessageDlg with something of my own where I can control.ownership.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I just ran into this problem as well.  It is easily reproduced by placing a break point on the MessageDlg call and then releasing the application.  This seems to result in the dialog appearing behind the current form.  No idea exactly what goes wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: @Kanitatlan - I found no answer. Instead I wrote my own version of MessageDlg. so i could make sure it comes up on top.